# Variable in SQL not working with prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have created small sql statement and I have tested it on phpmyadmin and it works fine, but when I try to call it from php, it returns false

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('
    SELECT 
       @newId := COALESCE( MAX( OrderNumber ) , 0 ) +1 
    FROM 
      GSM_Parent;
    INSERT INTO 
      GSM_Parent (OrderNumber)  
    VALUES ( (select @newId)) ');
```

Here $stmt is false.

Does these types of sql statements work with prepared statements or do I have to use normal mysqli calls?

Comment: `prepare` doesn't support multiple statements.

Comment: why you have 2 queries on the prepare statement ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer I needed this type of query, and because of that I have 2

Comment: You will have to execute 2 different queries.

Comment: INSERT INTO GSM_Parent (OrderNumber)  SELECT ...?

Comment: I tried but i got the error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can rewrite this query without using a MySQL variable..

```
INSERT INTO
GSM_Parent (OrderNumber)
values ( (SELECT COALESCE( MAX( OrderNumber ) , 0 ) +1 FROM GSM_Parent) )
```

> Thanks, but I got the following error:#1093 - You can't specify target
>   table 'GSM_Parent' for update in FROM clause .

Indeed i missed you used the same table twice, the query below should work.

```
INSERT INTO
  GSM_Parent (OrderNumber)
VALUES (
   (SELECT OrderNumber FROM (
     SELECT 
       (COALESCE(MAX(OrderNumber), 0) + 1) AS OrderNumber
     FROM
       GSM_Parent
     ) AS GSM_Parent
   ) 
)
```

@Jarth 's query from the comments is also possible then you need to write

```
INSERT INTO
  GSM_Parent (OrderNumber)
SELECT
  OrderNumber
FROM(
   SELECT COALESCE(MAX(OrderNumber), 0) +1 AS OrderNumber FROM GSM_Parent
) AS GSM_Parent
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got the following error:#1093 - You can't specify target table 'GSM_Parent' for update in FROM clause .

Comment: On third statement I tried `INSERT INTO GSM_Parent (OrderNumber)
VALUES ((SELECT OrderNumber FROM(SELECT COALESCE( MAX( OrderNumber ) , 0 ) +1 AS OrderNumber FROM GSM_Parent))` but I got Every derived table must have its own alias  error

Comment: i know i should have fomatted the queries from the start then i would be more clear i missed aliases when typing them out.. @worker it should be fixed now. Both queries should work.

Comment: After I copied edited ones it worked. Thank you very much, I was very close to second solution though